# Open AI Gym v0.26.0 Custom Environment TypeError: reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am making a maze environment for a project I am working on. When I attempt to test the environment I get the TypeError: reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'. Does anyone know what is causing this? I am using gym version 0.26.0. Here is my environment class (note the reset function):

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
import pygame
import numpy as np
import math
import random

class MazeEnv(gym.Env):
    metadata = {"render_modes": ["human", "rgb_array"], "render_fps": 4}
    
    
    def __init__(self, render_mode=None, size=10.0):
        self.size = size
        self.window_size = 512
        
        self.observation_space = spaces.Dict(
            {
                "agent": spaces.Box(low=0.0, high=10.0, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32),
                "target": spaces.Box(low=0.0, high=10.0, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
                }
            )
        
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=-math.pi, high=math.pi, shape = (1,))
        
        assert render_mode is None or render_mode in self.metadata["render_modes"]
        self.render_mode = render_mode
        
        self.window = None
        self.clock = None
        
        
    def _get_obs(self):
        return {"agent": self._agent_location, "target": self._target_location}
    
    
    def _get_info(self):
        return {"distance": np.linalg.norm(self._agent_location - self._target_location, ord=2)}
    
    
    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        super().reset(seed=seed)
        
        # agents starting location
        self._agent_location = [0.0, 10.0]
        self._target_location = [10.0, 0.0]
        
        observation = self._get_obs()
        info = self._get_info()
        
        if self.render_mode == "human":
            self._render_frame()
            
        return observation, info
    
    
    def step(self, action):
        terminated = False
        
        angle = random.gauss(action, math.pi/6)
        direction = [math.cos(angle)/2, math.sin(angle)/2]
        
        if self._agent_location[0] + direction[0] < 0.0 or self._agent_location[1] + direction[1] < 0.0 or self._agent_location[0] + direction[0] > 10.0 or self._agent_location[1] + direction[1] > 10.0:
            self._agent_location = [0.0, 10.0] ######### POSSIBLY RESET HERE?
        else:
            self._agent_location = self._agent_location + direction
            
        observation = self._get_obs()
        info = self._get_info()
        
        if info["distance"] < 0.5:
            terminated = True
        reward = 1 if terminated else 0
        
        if self.render_mode == "human":
            self._render_frame()
            
        return observation, reward, terminated, False, info
    
    
    def render(self):
        if self.render_mode == "rgb_array":
            return self._render_frame()
        
    def _render_frame(self):
        if self.window is None and self.render_mode == "human":
            pygame.init()
            pygame.display.init()
            self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.window_size, self.window_size))
        if self.clock is None and self.render_mode == "human":
            self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            
        canvas = pygame.Surface((self.window_size, self.window_size))
        canvas.fill((255, 255, 255))
        
        pygame.draw.circle(canvas, (255, 0, 0), self._target_location, 0.5, draw_top_left=True)
        
        pygame.draw.circle(canvas, (0,0,255), self._agent_location, 0.02)
        
        pygame.draw.line(canvas, (0,0,0), (0.0,0.0), (0.0,10.0))
        pygame.draw.line(canvas, (0,0,0), (0.0,0.0), (10.0,0.0))
        pygame.draw.line(canvas, (0,0,0), (10.0,0.0), (10.0,10.0))
        pygame.draw.line(canvas, (0,0,0), (0.0,10.0), (10.0,10.0))
        
        if self.render_mode == "human":
            # The following line copies our drawings from `canvas` to the visible window
            self.window.blit(canvas, canvas.get_rect())
            pygame.event.pump()
            pygame.display.update()

            # We need to ensure that human-rendering occurs at the predefined framerate.
            # The following line will automatically add a delay to keep the framerate stable.
            self.clock.tick(self.metadata["render_fps"])
        else:  # rgb_array
            return np.transpose(
                np.array(pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(canvas)), axes=(1, 0, 2)
            )
        
    def close(self):
        if self.window is not None:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
```

Above I am following the instructions located on the gym documentation site: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/environment_creation/

Here is my code to initialize and test the environment:

```
import gym

env = gym.make('MazeEnv-v0')

observation, info = env.reset()

for _ in range(1000):
    observation, reward, terminated, truncation, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    
    if terminated:
        observation, info = env.reset()
        
env.close()
```

...and here is the error that is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ...\Code\Maze Game\test.py:13 in <module>
    observation, info = env.reset()

  File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\wrappers\time_limit.py:68 in reset
    return self.env.reset(**kwargs)

  File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\maze_game.py:48 in reset
    super().reset(seed=seed)

TypeError: reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'
```

Comment: it looks like original `reset()` doesn't get argument `seed`. Maybe they changed it. How do you create class with env?

Comment: I use ` gym version 0.26.0.` but I can't reproduce your problem. But I don't use `anaconda`. Maybe `anaconda` uses older version of `gym`

Comment: Hello, I attempted to remove 'seed=seed' from super().reset() (i.e. just "super().reset()") in the definition of reset, however, I then get a reset() super.reset() NotImplementedError. I confirmed my gym version by via the function print(gym.__version__) and it is indeed 0.26.0

Comment: @furas I also edited the original post to include the full MazeEnv class so that you can try it with my class. If you have a chance to run it, please let me know if you run into the same issue. Thank you for the help! Also, please note that the class itself may have other issues as this is my first time creating a custom env.

Comment: code works correctly for me. Maybe add `print(gym.__version__)` before `class class MazeEnv(gym.Env):` to see what version it really uses.